# AWStats linking URL

Tags: awstats

I have a site that AWSTATS is saying 5 people clicked to get to my site in my stat report.  When I go to that link, I don't see anything referencing my site.

Is there somebody hiding my link?

Answer (score 2):

Many sites, like online news, Twitter etc, have dynamic content pages that are constantly being updated or refreshed. This content may have been archived or moved from the that particular page into the archives (or off entirely).

Try using the 'site' operator in Google to locate the reference to your site:
`site:theirwebaddress.com "yoururl"`

Answer (score 2):

There are a few possibilities:

1. As seriocomic mentioned, the link from their site to yours has moved to another page (or was removed)
2. [Referrer spam](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Referrer_spam) (most likely option if the other site is completely unrelated to your own)
3. The "link" was actually an embedded image or other multimedia content (in which case I'd expect you would see more than five visits, but perhaps their site isn't very popular)